# Nodemailer sending attachment using sendinblue

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, nodemailer

I'm using React-Bootstrap but it is not allowing me to send attachments. It was working before on Sendinblue.

Complaint.JS

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Col,
  Container,
  FloatingLabel,
  Form,
  Row,
  Button,
} from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Complaint() {
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);

  const [status, setStatus] = useState("Submit");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    const form = e.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }

    setValidated(true);
    setStatus("Sending...");
    const {
      complainantName,
      violatorName,
      complainantAddress,
      violatorAddress,
      phoneNumber,
      emailAddress,
      violation,
      filesUpload,
    } = e.target.elements;
    let details = {
      cName: complainantName.value,
      cAddress: complainantAddress.value,
      phone: phoneNumber.value,
      email: emailAddress.value,
      vName: violatorName.value,
      vAddress: violatorAddress.value,
      violation: violation.value,
      attachments: filesUpload.value,
    };

    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/complaint", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(details),
    });
    setStatus("Submit");
    let result = await response.json();
    alert(result.status);
    if (response) setStatus(response.statusText);
  };
  return (
    <Container className="pt-4">
      <h4>Complaint Form</h4>
      <hr />
      <p>
        This is the Shadow Lakes Homeowners' Association Board of Directors'
        official process for addressing complaints. All complaints will be
        confidential and timely handled. The description of the violation must
        include the nature of and date of the alleged violation with an
        explanation of the factual basis of the complaint. (Who, What, Where,
        When, etc.).{" "}
        <strong>
          Every input boxes must be filled and validated, or the complaint form
          will be automatically rejected.
        </strong>
      </p>
      <Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <FloatingLabel
                className="mb-3"
                controlId="complainantName"
                label="Complainant's Name"
              >
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Complainant's Name"
                  required
                />
              </FloatingLabel>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FloatingLabel
                className="mb-3"
                controlId="violatorName"
                label="Violator's Name"
              >
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Violator's Name"
                  required
                />
              </FloatingLabel>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <FloatingLabel
                className="mb-3"
                controlId="complainantAddress"
                label="Complainant's Address"
              >
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Complainant's Address"
                  required
                />
              </FloatingLabel>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FloatingLabel
                className="mb-3"
                controlId="violatorAddress"
                label="Violator's Address"
              >
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Violator's Address"
                  required
                />
              </FloatingLabel>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <FloatingLabel
                className="mb-3"
                controlId="phoneNumber"
                label="Phone Number"
              >
                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
                <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                  Phone Number is not to be share with anyone.
                </Form.Text>
              </FloatingLabel>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FloatingLabel
                className="mb-3"
                controlId="emailAddress"
                label="Email Address"
              >
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Email Address"
                  required
                />
                <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                  Email address is not to be share with anyone.
                </Form.Text>
              </FloatingLabel>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <FloatingLabel
                controlId="violation"
                label="Description of alleged violation"
                className="mb-3"
              >
                <Form.Control
                  as="textarea"
                  placeholder="Description of alleged violation"
                  style={{ height: "200px" }}
                  required
                />
                <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                  Description of the alleged violation must be related to Deed
                  Restrictions. Please review the{" "}
                  <a href="/deed-restrictions" className="text-black-50">
                    Deed Restrictions
                  </a>{" "}
                  if unsure of the violation.
                </Form.Text>
              </FloatingLabel>
            </Col>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Form.Label>Multiple Photos Allowed</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  controlId="filesUpload"
                  className="mb-3"
                  type="file"
                  multiple
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Row>
        </Form.Group>
        <Button type="submit" value={"submit"}>
          {status}
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Server.js

```
router.post("/complaint", (req, res) => {
  const cName = req.body.cName;
  const cAddress = req.body.cAddress;
  const phone = req.body.phone;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const vName = req.body.vName;
  const vAddress = req.body.vAddress;
  const violation = req.body.violation;

  const mail = {
    from: "hello@example.com",
    to: "hello@example.com",
    subject: `Complaint from ${cName} on ${vName}`,
    html: `The message is from ${cName} <br />
    Complaint's Name: ${cName} <br />
    Complaint's address: ${cAddress} <br />
    Email: ${email} <br />
    Phone: ${phone} <br />
    Violator's Name: ${vName} <br />
    Violator's Address: ${vAddress} <br />
    Violation: ${violation} <br />
    Attachment Image(s):<img src="cid:imageFiles" />`,
    attachments: [
      {
        filename: "image.png",
        path: "/files/images/",
        cid: "imageFiles",
      },
    ],
  };
  contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json({ status: "ERROR" });
    } else {
      res.json({ status: "Message has been sent" });
    }
  });
});
```

There are no error messages when the form is sent. I have changed it directly from the cPanel SMTP and still have the issues. If I remove the codes, then the form will work.

```
      {
        filename: "image.png",
        path: "/files/images/",
        cid: "imageFiles",
      },
    ],
```

I have had it with

```
<Form.Group controlId="filesUpload" className="mb-3">
   <Form.Label>Multiple Photos Allowed</Form.Label>
   <Form.Control type="file" multiple />
</ Form.Group>
```

I think I am overlooking something. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
attachments: [
  {
    filename: 'somefile.txt',
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    content: 'string attachment example'
  },
],
```

[Nodemailer Attachment Empty but filename is attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72987167/nodemailer-attachment-empty-but-filename-is-attached)